# django 404 when opening static folder

Tags: python, django

I have created a /static/ folder in my project's root and changed the settings thusly:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

But when I open my localhost/static, it produces a 404 error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Django 1.3+:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = path.join(TOP_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

For apache:

```
Alias /static /var/my/site/static
<Directory /var/my/site/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aiming at a particular file? If not then theres your problem, if you are aiming at a file, are you sure its in the correct directory?

Comment: No I'm trying to open a particular file (static/css/main.css)

Comment: @chubak - try printing os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") from somewhere in your code and watch the debug out put.

Also, what version of django are you running? I'm not sure why you'd have submodules of staticfiles rather than just 
django.contrib.staticfiles

which is what the docs specify

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `manage.py collectstatic` first.

Note: It's also possible that going to `/static` is the cause (missing the trailing slash) though django should redirect.

Comment: I ran collectstatic, still, I get 404 when I try to access /static/css/main.css

Comment: Do you have this in your urls.py file? `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`